# Unicorn does not use default ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, unicorn

I have an rails app using unicorn, nginx on aws.
I have just updated ruby version from 2.0 to 2.2.1.

`ruby -v` returns

> ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]

I was tried to restart unicorn service

```
sudo service unicorn_game-mercenaries_production stop
sudo service unicorn_game-mercenaries_production start
```

and the result was

> /home/gamemercs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@game-mercenaries/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:412:in
>   `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile
>   specified 2.2.1 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)    from
>   /home/gamemercs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@game-mercenaries/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:123:in`
>   setup'   from
>   /home/gamemercs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@game-mercenaries/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'   from
>   /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from
>   /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'

Here is my unicorn.rb:

```
working_directory "/home/gamemercs/rails_apps/game-mercenaries/current"
pid "/home/gamemercs/rails_apps/game-mercenaries/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stdout_path "/home/gamemercs/rails_apps/game-mercenaries/shared/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
stderr_path "/home/gamemercs/rails_apps/game-mercenaries/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log"


listen "/tmp/unicorn.game-mercenaries_production.sock"


worker_processes 2
timeout 30

preload_app true

before_exec do |server|
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = "/home/gamemercs/rails_apps/game-mercenaries/current/Gemfile"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # Disconnect since the database connection will not carry over
  if defined? ActiveRecord::Base
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  # Quit the old unicorn process
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end

  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis.quit
  end
  p 'stop'

  sleep 1
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # Start up the database connection again in the worker
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

  p 'start'
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'
  end
end
```

/etc/init.d/unicorn_game-mercenaries_production

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: unicorn
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description: Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/gamemercs/rails_apps/game-mercenaries/current
PID=/home/gamemercs/rails_apps/game-mercenaries/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid

AS_USER=gamemercs
CMD="export HOME; true "${HOME:=$(getent passwd "$AS_USER" | cut -d: -f6;)}" ; cd $APP_ROOT && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.1@game-mercenaries do bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/gamemercs/rails_apps/game-mercenaries/shared/config/unicorn.rb -E production"

set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig USR2 && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

I'd appreciate any help.
how can I make unicorn to use default ruby(v2.2.1)?

Comment: Seems there is an issue in /etc/init.d/unicorn_game-mercenaries_production.
Running "sudo service unicorn_game-mercenaries_production start" got an error but "sudo bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/gamemercs/rails_apps/game-mercenaries/shared/config/unicorn.rb -E production" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please edit the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH in `/etc/init.d/unicorn`, to reflect your new ruby version path/number?

Comment: Don't forget to stop and start again unicorn and please mark as accepted if this answer was helpful.

Comment: can you please check in /etc/unicorn or maybe in /etc/init.d/   with some other name ? or /etc/default/unicorn ?

Comment: but you have /etc/init.d/unicorn_game-mercenaries_production ? this is the second file you pasted above but there is no GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH keys there I see also I see you are using rvm

Comment: can you run in terminal this command and check what version is choose 'rvm list'

Comment: you can edit this file by using production installer editors like vim or nano.  for nano you should run command: sudo nano  /etc/init.d/unicorn_game-mercenaries_production       and then you can update file when you finish changes then press ctrl+x and next press y to save changes.  But I suggest you to find good tutorial about deploying rails app with rvm and unicorn to check the whole procedure and to be sure that you are not missing something else.  Here are some tutorials: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: And this also: https://launchschool.com/blog/setting-up-your-production-server-with-nginx-and-unicorn

Comment: In general check these tutorials pasted above you will see in general from theirs examples. You put there path to current ruby installation gem directory. But please use first the few tutorials to get familiar with procedure of setting unicorn,

Comment: I'm not sure how can I change the ruby version of unicorn from above tutorials.